# VB.net: deploy application to website server

Tags: vb.net

I have written a vb.net application that I want to put on a webpage (like a Java applet). My application connects to an external website to scrape data (using the WebBrowser control). How do I put my application online?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a Windows Form application inside a browser like a plugin (unless you do a lot of work to get it to run as an ActiveX control and that would only be IE).

Perhaps you could make an installer using ClickOnce or something else?